# How to pick a random string from an array on mouse press in Processing

Tags: processing

I want to do the following in Processing:

- Display text on the screen
- When mouse is not pressed, always display the first string in the array
- When mouse is pressed, choose a random string from the array and have this string persist until the mouse is pressed again

I tried moving "int index = int(random(0, 3));" two draw() but this picks a random string many times a second, and I want it to pick it once until I press the mouse again.

In draw(), the value of index is always zero. It only changes in mousePressed().

Here's my code:

```
String[] sentences = { // defines an array of three strings
  "Sentence one",
  "Sentence two",
  "Sentence three",
};

int index = 0; // initializes variable "index" to zero

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  text(sentences[index], 10, 100); // picks a random sentence from the array
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mousePressed == true) { // when mouse pressed 
    int index = int(random(0, 3)); // picks a random value for index: either 0,1,2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're experiencing [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).
This line:

```
int index = int(random(0, 3)); // picks a random value for index: either 0,1,2
```

declares `index` as a **local** variable, so within that scope only it shadows the global variable.

you probably meant

```
index = int(random(0, 3)); // picks a random value for index: either 0,1,2
```

(you're defining and assigning `index` at the top of your code, but in `mousePressed()` you just want to assign a different variable to the previously defined variable)

Off topic:

- `if (mousePressed == true)` is the same as `if (mousePressed)`, but in this context (within the `mousePressed()` function is redundant since it will always be true there
- you're not handling the "when the mouse is not pressed" case: `mouseReleased()` can help with that.

Here's a modified version of your code reflecting the above:

```java
String[] sentences = { // defines an array of three strings
  "Sentence one",
  "Sentence two",
  "Sentence three",
};

int index = 0; // initializes variable "index" to zero

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  text(sentences[index], 10, 100); // displays sentence at index from the array
}

// when mouse pressed 
void mousePressed() {
  index = int(random(3)); // picks a random value for index: either 0,1,2
}
// when mouse released
void mouseReleased() {
  index = 0; // always displays the 1st sentence when mouse is not pressed
}
```